# Install npm for grunt

Tags: unix, npm, gruntjs

I want install grunt
npm doesn't work
http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

But I have this:

```
$ npm install -g grunt-cli
-bash: npm: command not found
```

Thanks

Comment: did you install [node](http://nodejs.org/)?

Comment: Install nodejs, npm first.

Answer (score 3):

Go here: http://nodejs.org/ and click the big green install button.